# NHibernate Caching Objects Based on Parent Class's ID

Tags: c#, nhibernate, caching, joined-subclass, session-cache

I have the following definitions for the Animal and Dog types. Note that the ID for the object is the AnimalID:

```
<class name="Animal" table="Animals">
    <id name="Id" type="System.Int32" column="AnimalID">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="IsBig" column="IsBig" type="System.Bool" not-null="true" />  
</class>

<joined-subclass name="Dog" table="Dogs" extends="Animal">
    <key column="AnimalID" />
    <property name="OwnerID" column="OwnerID" type="System.Int32" non-null="true" />
    <property name="IsStrong" column="IsStrong" type="System.Bool" non-null="true" />
</joined-subclass>
```

Let's say I have the following information in my database:

```
in table Animals:

AnimalID    IsBig
--------    -----
10          True

in table Dogs:

AnimalID    OwnerID    IsStrong
--------    -------    --------
10          1          True
10          2          False
```

First, I query for the Dog where OwnerID = 1. In the same session, I query for the Dog where OwnerID = 2. Because of NHibernate's Session cache, the second query returns a Dog object where OwnerID = 1 and IsStrong = True, where it should return a Dog object where OwnerID = 2 and IsStrong = False.

NHibernate automatically caches objects by their ID (primary key) column, so requesting the Dog the second time ends up retrieving an object with the same key. I can solve this problem by calling ISession.Evict() on the object, but that seems like a hack.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: can you create a runnable testcase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must ensure you're using different keys for different instances. In your case you're actually violating this rule: Dogs table exposes parts of *two* instances *sharing the same key*.

So Dogs.AnimalID *must* be marked as primary key, but in your case it isn't. If it would be marked as PK, you couldn't get such content at all.

Comment: So from the point of NH there is a single instance of Animal in this case: the one having AnimalID==10. But your database schema actually allows you to store multiple rows for this instance in Dogs table - just because there is no primary key (although it must be there).

Comment: That is sort of what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

With respect, the question you *should* be asking is "how do I model this correctly?"

Your Dogs table says that dog 10 is owned by owner 1 and is strong, but, **at the same time**, dog 10 is owned by owner 2 and is NOT strong.

Somehow, I don't think that's what you meant.

If you'll explain in more detail what you're trying to model, perhaps we can make some suggestions.

Comment: Since this seems like a different question, I created a different one here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871043/nhibernate-how-to-correctly-model-this-schema

Comment: ok...that one's not much clearer to me, i'm afraid. It seems like you're combining two concepts here: 1) mapping of class hierarchies, and 2) many-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Make AnimalID and OwnerID a composite primary key.

Comment: That will not work because the Dog is joined to it's parent class by the AnimalID column. If Dog defined (AnimalID, OwnerID) as a composite key, it could not be joined to the Animal class by AnimalID.