# NHibernate: How to Correctly Model This Schema

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have these related tables in my database:

```
table [Files]:
FileID    FileName
------    --------
1         /data/foo.jpeg
2         /data/bar.gif

table [Attachments]:
FileID    DocumentID    Caption
------    ----------    -------
1         10            Foo is awesome.
1         20            Foo is horrible.
2         10            Bars are my favorite.

table [Documents]:
DocumentID    Title
----------    -----
10            Things Jack loves.
20            Stuff Mary hates.
```

This is how they are currently mapped in NHibernate:

```
<class name="File" table="Files">
    <id name="Id" type="System.Int32" column="FileID">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="FileName" column="FileName" type="System.String" />  
</class>

<joined-subclass name="Attachment" table="Attachments" extends="File">
    <key column="FileID" />
    <property name="DocumentID" column="DocumentID" type="System.Int32" />
    <property name="Caption" column="Caption" type="System.String" />
</joined-subclass>

<class name="Document" table="Documents">
    <id name="Id" type="System.Int32" column="DocumentID">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Title" column="Title" type="System.String" />
</class>
```

I know that this mapping does not quite fit the schema for the Attachments table.
Is there a better way to map these tables?

(This is related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849195/nhibernate-caches-objects-based-on-parents-id).)

Comment: Just as a side note, not an actual answer to your question, your type declarations in your mapping file don't need to explicitly state "System.String", you can simply just put in "string".

Comment: You don't even need to specify the type in most instances. NHibernate will use the property type by default. There are some cases where you want to, such as enums or custom types though.

Comment: Same for name/column. NHibernate uses the convention that the column name is the same as the property name, unless you specify otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on the above answer, you can use the many-to-one element to set up the relationship and use collection mapping to make the relationship bi-directional, which seems like it could be useful to your schema.

You'd use the many-to-one element in the mapping for the attachments. For example,

```
<many-to-one name="File" class="File" column="FileID"/>
```

And you can specify the inverse on the mapping for files:

```
<set name="Attachments" inverse="true" lazy="true">
    <key column="FileID" />
    <one-to-many class="Attachment" />
</set>
```

You can do the same thing for the documents. Names above are just taken from the schema, but you'd still need to make sure they match their classes and etc. But that's the overall idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to enforce relationship between Attachment and Document? If true just refer to ["many-to-one" element](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone).